# Select a row from a database which contains part of a variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need a MySQL query to search the database for any rows that contain a username in the `$friend_array` variable.

For example, if this was the case:

```
$friend_array = "ksk,google,bob,steve,dunno,anotheruser";
```

and there were rows in the 'Posts' database where the username is `bob`, then I would want a query to select this.

Also if it could select all the rows which contains a user from the friend array, so for example if there were rows in the 'Posts' database with users from the same array (e.g. there was one row with `ksk` and another with `steve`) then I would want them both selected in the query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the `IN` clause

Comment: Umm `$friend_array` does not look like an array, more like a comma seperated list. Can you clarify please

Comment: $sql = "select * from database where username IN ($friend_array)";

Comment: Checkout mysql find in set http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

starting from the fact that `$friend_array` is a string, in your example.

Let's code:

```
<?php
    /* if $friend_array is a string  starts from here*/
    $friend_array = "ksk,google,bob,steve,dunno,anotheruser"; // your string
    $friend_array = explode(',', $friend_array); // transform it to array

    /* if $friend_array is an array starts from here */
    //Now prepare a String for SQL IN operator
    $friend_array = implode(', ',array_map(function($a){return "'" . $a . "'";}, $friend_array));

   //the SQL
   $sql = "select * from Posts where user_name in ($friend_array)";
?>
```

Comment: What was the reason to copy my answer? :)

Comment: It is not a copy, but a more verbose version ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a WHERE IN statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Posts 
WHERE user_name IN ("ksk", "google", "bob", "steve", "dunno", "anotheruser");
```

Comment: Might be useful to tell OP how to convert `"ksk,google,bob,steve,dunno,anotheruser"` into `'"ksk","google","bob","steve","dunno","anotheruser"'`

Answer (score 0):

Use IN clause for your result:

```
Select * from `tableName` 
Where userName IN ("ksk","google","bob","steve",...)
```

Comment: Might be useful to tell OP how to convert `"ksk,google,bob,steve,dunno,anotheruser"` into `'"ksk","google","bob","steve","dunno","anotheruser"'`

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
"SELECT * 
FROM Posts 
WHERE user_name IN (".implode(',', array_map(function ($value) { return "'".$value."'"; }, explode(',', $friend_array))).");"
```